# Measure distance between a circle and an ellipse center in autocad/inventor

Tags: robotics, autocad, autodesk-inventor

I am working on a robotics project, I got a SolidWorks sldprt/step model of the robot(cca. 40 solids). However, I have only Autocad/and Inventor available.

I need to measure a distance from n ellipse center (endpoint) and a circle center - joint axis.

Unfortunately, the ellipse and the circle lay in different z levels, are hollow and belong to different solids. No matter what I try, I can get neither the inventor nor the autocad to measure the distance using annotate or measure.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you not project geometry onto one or other sketch plane or a new one?

Comment: ^This is the answer. If you don't need it to 10 decimal places, you can just start a sketch on a plane, and draw a line by eye and measure that. If you *do* need extra precision, then projecting the geometry and mating the line is required.